# strange optional error in Swift

Tags: swift, string, firebase, option-type

Okay, so basically I am following a tutorial on udemy on how to create a chat with Backendless and Firebase. However, I prefer not to use Backendless, because I don't want to rely on 2 providers - so I want to stick to Firebase only. Therefore, I am currently converting my code to Firebase.

I have a view controller that displays a unique page for each UID - from a database that I have. The UID is stored as a `String`, and is assigned upon a segue from another table view controller (this works fine). After that, I fetch the data that I want from the user, with the UID. I have a "Start Chat" button that is supposed to create a new chat.

In this tutorial, the tutor has set a protocol (delegate) that is triggering another function from another view controller. This is what it looks like:

```
protocol ChooseUserDelegate {
    func createChatroom(withUser: String)
}

var delegate: ChooseUserDelegate!
```

and in my chat `@IBAction`, I have this code:

```
@IBAction func StartChat(sender: AnyObject) {

    let userID = uid
    if let theId = userID as? String {
        delegate.createChat(String(theId))
    }

}
```

(The code above is all in the same VC.).

In another view controller, where the `createChat()` function is stored, is the following code:

```
class AnotherVC UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ChooseUserDelegate{

    func createChat(withUser: String) {

        print(withUser)

    }

}
```

The problem is that I can't get to call `createChat()`, because of an optional error (unwrapping) on the `delegate.createChat(String(theId))`.

Edit: Even with a "" input, I get an error. I am really confused now. Is it something wrong with my delegate?

Comment: Check your delegate variable declaration.

Comment: @RohitKP As far as I am concerned, it's correct. I can update my post with more code.

Comment: Could you please format your question to make it legible?

Comment: "However, I get an optional error" What error do you get? I can't even figure out from your question what line triggers the error or what the error is. If you want help, take some time to describe the problem, please.

Comment: The post is updated now, and hopefully it contains enough information.

Comment: Where are you assigning the delegate i.e.  self.delegate = myDelegate or myViewController.delegate = myDelegate? Are you storing a reference somewhere? i.e. weak var delegate: MyCoolDelegate?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this is the best use of delegates. You can call functions in other classes without the use of a delegate and in this case, it sounds like you select a user from a list you want to chat with, that then segues to another view controller that handles the actual chat. You can simply pass the data in the segue or via representedObject. The receiving viewController would then load the appropriate data based on the data that was passed to it.

Answer (score 2):

The only part of your code that is optional is `delegate` (because you correctly unwrapped `userID`). Therefore, the error must be due to `delegate` being `nil`. Make sure that you set `delegate` before calling `StartChat()`.

The line `var delegate: ChooseUserDelegate!` does not initialize a delegate. When you write `ChooseUserDelegate!` you are only defining the type of the `delegate` variable. It is automatically set to `nil`. To initialize a new instance of `ChooseUserDelegate` you would need to write something like:

```
var delegate: ChooseUserDelegate! = ChooseUserDelegate()
```

There are a few other ways you could clean up your code. Method names should be llamaCase, not CamelCase, so you should rename `StartChat()` to `startChat()` (be sure to reconnect in interface builder). The body of that method has three different names for the same variable, `uid`. See how simple it could be:

```
@IBAction func startChat(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let uid = uid as? String {
        delegate.createChat(uid)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one more thing to mention, the method in the protocol should be:
`func createChat(withUser: String)`

Comment: I have initialized the delegate under my main class (on top).

Comment: @askaale you can print the delegate out to see if it is nil

Comment: @chengsam While trying to print it, I yet again get an optional value-error.

Comment: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", with a pointer at the delegate.createChat(uid). @chengsam

Comment: How did you set the delegate?

Comment: Thanks for helping, but the initialization of the delegate doesn't work though.

Comment: Please show how you initialized the delegate and what error you received.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let theId = userID {
    delegate.createChat(String(theId))
}
```

Comment: Conditional binding must have optional type (?), that's why this doesn't work either :/

Comment: But thanks for trying to help. Really appreciate it! I can't seem to figure it out myself either.

Comment: Still the same error. I really have no idea what this is, even with a "value"-type, it gives me an error...

Comment: Why can't you just use the userID variable? Maybe it can be nil?

Comment: It is not nil, as I can print (userID) and get a unwrapped output. However, I believe the problem lies in my delegate, but I can't seem to understand how..